# Limit the menu level on node add/edit page

Tags: routes

On node add/edit page we have a menu settings option. This option by default show all the nodes in the main menu under Parent Item tab. Is there a way we can limit the nodes in the menu(under parent item) to only first two levels.
 [image]

Comment: [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and manually remove any `#options` more than 2 levels deep?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block and see it it will work for your use case.

Comment: @FelixEve while I can do that I was thinking if we can limit it during the menu population itself so that we don't need to waste so many resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Menu Performance Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menuperformance) does exactly that.

Drupal is already aware of this issue and has a variable `menu_override_parent_selector` which can be leveraged by other modules to come up with their own implementation of the menu handlers on node edit page.

As the project page reads

> Menuperformance takes advantage of this, and sets the variable when
>   installed. It then proceeds to add its own AJAX based parent menu item
>   selector widgets for the node edit, node type edit and vocabulary edit
>   pages.

How to Use from README.txt

> - Enable the module.
> - Go to /admin/config/user-interface/menuperformance , and activate the  module. Checking the checkbox sets Drupal variable 
>     menu_override_parent_selector.
> - After the module is activated, the menu item selectors on the above  mentioned pages should have been replaced with a multiple dropdown 
>     AJAX-powered selector instead of the standard single dropdown.